# layout issue while adding searchView in toolbar ( fragment )

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar

in my fragment i added a toolbar now am trying to add here a searchView which expands and collapse its working fine on a action bar but am having layout issue while using this on my toolbar :

here's my toolbar and below of that there's 2 buttons 
my issue #1 is that here my icon of searchView is not visible but when you touch below the clock (5:16 in the status bar ) , searchView  expands see second image

[image]

you can see that now searchView is visible and the title  (its a textView)  of toolbar shifted to left for making room for the searchView which is also a issue and when am typing anything on search view the colour of text is not visible (but searchView is working fine ) only the searched text is not visible in the searchView

[image]

when i again  tap below at the clock my searchView collapses and title also set   on  its right position

here's my xml file of fragment :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Channel"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

  .... other ui elements 
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

searchView menu xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/done"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

this fragment is inside a tabLayout and i can't use Actionbar instead of toolbar 
any idea how can i fix this ?or why its happening  ? please let me know it'll be so helpful for me

inside my fragment class :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.menu_action_next){
        //Do whatever you want to do

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    MenuInflater menuInflater = inflater;
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_bar_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = null;
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    }

    if (searchView != null )
    {

        searchView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(onQueryTextListener);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(onCloseListener);


    }
}
```

UPDATE:

after adding `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` in my search menu xml (thanks to @Ashwinikutre) i got this

now icon is visible

[image]

and its expanding by removing title which is fine but no text colour and close button (which is now on another side but its invisible )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="80"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

**search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_close"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding the above code to onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Comment: tried your suggestion , still the same problem exists

Comment: hey please check the update question your  `"ifRoom|collapseActionView"` did some of the job

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly add the following attribute to show it is a search view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Of course, you probably have this correctly setup too

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.global_search, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(item);

    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_customers));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I am going to have to try this on my project then let you know; sounds interesting